# How does Haskell do pattern matching without us defining an Eq on our data types?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I have defined a binary tree:

```
data Tree = Null | Node Tree Int Tree
```

and have implemented a function that'll yield the sum of the values of all its nodes:

```
sumOfValues :: Tree -> Int
sumOfValues Null = 0
sumOfValues (Node Null v Null) = v
sumOfValues (Node Null v t2) = v + (sumOfValues t2)
sumOfValues (Node t1 v Null) = v + (sumOfValues t1)
sumOfValues (Node t1 v t2) = v + (sumOfValues t1) + (sumOfValues t2)
```

It works as expected. I had the idea of also trying to implement it using guards:

```
sumOfValues2 :: Tree -> Int
sumOfValues2 Null = 0
sumOfValues2 (Node t1 v t2)
    | t1 == Null && t2 == Null  = v
    | t1 == Null            = v + (sumOfValues2 t2)
    |               t2 == Null  = v + (sumOfValues2 t1)
    |   otherwise       = v + (sumOfValues2 t1) + (sumOfValues2 t2)
```

but this one doesn't work because I haven't implemented `Eq`, I believe:

> ```
> No instance for (Eq Tree)
>   arising from a use of `==' at zzz3.hs:13:3-12
> Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Eq Tree)
> In the first argument of `(&&)', namely `t1 == Null'
> In the expression: t1 == Null && t2 == Null
> In a stmt of a pattern guard for
>              the definition of `sumOfValues2':
>         t1 == Null && t2 == Null
> ```

The question that has to be made, then, is how can Haskell make pattern matching without knowing when a passed argument matches, without resorting to `Eq`?

### Edit

Your arguments seem to revolve around the fact that Haskell is not indeed comparing the arguments of the function, but instead on the "form" and types of signature to know which sub-function to match. But how about this?

```
f :: Int -> Int -> Int
f 1 _ = 666
f 2 _ = 777
f _ 1 = 888
f _ _ = 999
```

When running `f 2 9`, won't it have to use `Eq` to know which one of the subfunctions is the right one? All of them are equal (contrary to my initial Tree example when we had Tree/Node/Null). Or is the actual definition of an `Int` something like

```
data Int = -2^32 | -109212 ... | 0 | ... +2^32
```

?

Comment: When you're pattern matching against numbers, you are using the `Eq` class. Numeric literals are not constructors. If they were, they couldn't have the type `Num a => a`. Note that `Num` requires `Eq`. If you define a `Num` instance with a funky `Eq` instance, pattern matching will behave accordingly (i.e. if `(fromInteger 42 :: MyInt) == fromInteger 23` is true, the pattern `23` will also match the value `42 :: MyInt`).

Comment: Just so you know, not all the 32 bits are available to represent Int. On my machine, `maxBound :: Int` returns 2147483647, 2^31 - 1.

Comment: Yes I know. But for the context of the question, I just didn't care.

Comment: FYI pattern guards don't require Eq - they require boolean expressions, which you have here constructed using Eq.

Comment: btw, if you needed `Eq` for pattern-matching, it would be rather hard to define `Eq` instances in the first place yourself... ;-)

Comment: @Wei Hu: Actually, they do. Think about it: maxBound = 2147483647 = 2^31 - 1, minBound = -2147483648 = 2^32, than add 0, so you get: 2^31 + 2^31-1 +1 = 2^32, what do you want more?

Comment: @FuZxxl, oops, you're right. I was confused by [-2^29, 2^29 - 1] specified in Haskell Report, and OCaml int that gets one bit stolen for tagging.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For pattern matching, Haskell uses the structure of the value and the constructors used. For example, if you evaluate

```
sumOfValues (Node Null 5 (Node Null 10 Null))
```

it checks the patterns from top to bottom:

- the first one, `Null`, doesn't match because it has a different structure
- the second one, `(Node Null v Null)`, doesn't match because the last component, `Null`, has a different structure than `(Node Null 10 Null)` (pattern matching proceeds recursively)
- the third one matches with `v` bound to 5 and `t2` bound to `(Node Null 10 Null)`.

`Eq` and the == operator it defines are an unrelated mechanism; making `Tree` an instance of `Eq` won't change how pattern matching works.

I think your thinking here is a bit backward: Pattern matching is the most basic way of using a value in Haskell; except for some basic types like `Int`, `Eq` is implemented using pattern matching, not the other way around.

#### Pattern matching and numbers

It turns out numeric literals are a special case. According to the Haskell report ([link](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#sect3.17.2)):

> Matching a numeric, character, or string literal pattern *k* against a value *v* succeeds if *v* == *k*, where == is overloaded based on the type of the pattern.

Comment: Your edit is wrong. If `0` etc. were constructors for the Int type, they would have type `Int`, not `Num a => a`. Also pattern matching on numbers does use the `Eq` instance of the numeric type in question.

Comment: @sepp2k: You're right, pattern matching with numeric literals is special. I've edited my answer to correct that.

Answer (score 8):

The thing you're missing is that you're assuming `Null` is some constant value like in C or Java. It's not — it's a constructor for the Tree type.

Pattern-matches do construction in reverse. Instead of you providing two values to the constructor and it gives you a value of the appropriate type, you provide a value of the type to the constructor and it gives you the constituent values that make up the type. The language knows which branch of the discriminated union was used to construct the value, so it can match against the correct pattern. Thus, there is no need for equality because it's all just constructors and variables — no actual values are being compared (or even necessarily evaluated).

#### With regards to your edit about Ints:

Yes, Int is basically a type with an obscenely large number of constructors along the lines of `-2 | -1 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 …`. It's a bit handwavy, but it works in practice.

Comment: Your edit is wrong. If `0` etc. were constructors for the `Int` type, they would have type `Int`, not `Num a => a`. Also pattern matching on numbers *does* use the `Eq` instance of the numeric type in question.

Comment: I think that the point to note is that the Int class could have been implemented like that but the point is that (as far as I understand it) a little hackery was done on all numbers for speed reasons.

Comment: @Robert: And that point is wrong. The reason that `Int` is not implemented that way has nothing to do with speed. The reason is that if `Int` were implemented that way, you couldn't use e.g. `42` as a value of type `Integer` or `Double` and thus the whole `Num` system would be defunct.

Comment: Could you talk a little bit more about this? "The language knows which branch of the discriminated union was used to construct the value, so it can match against the correct pattern." Where is it documented what kind of metadata the language "remembers" about instances? I understand mathematically I can expect this behavior out of Church encoding something something, but putting on my software engineer hat, would like to see docs of some kind.

Answer (score 7):

Haskell knows what type constructor was used to construct a particular instance, and that's all it needs in order to pattern match successfully.

Answer (score 2):

At *some* point you need pattern matching when you don't want to use Eq. E.g. you could define

```
isEmpty :: Tree -> Bool
isEmpty Null = True
isEmpty _ = False

sumOfValues2 :: Tree -> Int
sumOfValues2 Null = 0
sumOfValues2 (Node t1 v t2)
    | isEmpty t1 && isEmpty t2 = v
    | isEmpty t1 = v + (sumOfValues2 t2)
    | isEmpty t2 = v + (sumOfValues2 t1)
    | otherwise = v + (sumOfValues2 t1) + (sumOfValues2 t2)
```

BTW, you don't need all that cases, just this:

```
sumOfValues :: Tree -> Int
sumOfValues Null = 0
sumOfValues (Node t1 v t2) = v + (sumOfValues t1) + (sumOfValues t2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can think of the data constructors as tags. To do a pattern matching on a value of `Tree`, the compiled code extracts the tag and just knows which branch to dispatch to. It doesn't care about the real value, so you don't need `Eq`.

Answer (score 1):

Pattern matching depends on the syntax. E.g. if you write a pattern involving constructors, pattern matching by constructors is what you'll get. If you write a pattern involving litteral expressions (and litteral floating point values or integers are just that) you get an equality test (from the Eq class) using whatever overloaded definition of the (==) operator your type may provide.

So if you overload your Fred data type which is of class Num and has a constructor, also called Fred you could define equality against Integers by checking if the given Integer is 1. Now in that weird scenario, unless I'm overlooking something, the following ought to work:

```
getFred :: Fred -- get a Fred
getFred = Fred -- invoke the Fred constructor

testFred :: Fred -> Bool -- tests if Fred's equality operator considers 1 equal to Fred
testFred 1 = True -- overloaded (==) tests against 1, so should be true
testFred _ = False -- shouldn't happen, then...

isFredOne = testFred $ getFred -- returns True
```

Answer (score 0):

I justify this type of thing to myself by saying that pattern matching is core to what Haskell is - the Eq typeclass is not.

So while there are features similar to pattern matching which require Eq, they are not pattern matching and could be implemented on top of pattern matching.