# Haskell: Why does pattern matching work for types without being instances of equality?

Tags: haskell, types, pattern-matching

I was wondering how pattern matching in Haskell works. I am aware of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718084/how-does-haskell-do-pattern-matching-without-us-defining-an-eq-on-our-data-types), but could not quite understand the answers therein.

- The answers state that types are matched by Boolean expressions, but how is this possible?
- The other thing I got was pattern matching is more general than `(==)` and `Eq` is implemented by use of pattern matching.

Can you tell me why `match` and `match3` are working even if I omit `deriving (Eq)` in the following code snippet, (it is clear why `match2` is failing)?

```
data MyType = TypeA | TypeB
            deriving (Eq)

match :: MyType -> String
match TypeA = "this is type A"
match TypeB = "this is type B"

match2 :: MyType -> String
match2 a | a == TypeA = "this is type A matched by equality"
         | a == TypeB = "this is type B matched by equality"
         | otherwise = "this is neither type A nor type B"

match3 :: MyType -> String
match3 a = case a of TypeA -> "this is type A matched by case expression"
                     TypeB -> "this is type B matched by case expression"

main :: IO ()
main = do
    (print . match) TypeA
    (print . match) TypeB
    (print . match2) TypeA
    (print . match2) TypeB
    (print . match3) TypeA
    (print . match3) TypeB
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just want to point out that data types and pattern matching (to a first approximation) are merely useful but redundant language features, that can be implemented purely using lambda calculus.  If you understand how to implement them in lambda calculus, you can understand why they don't need `Eq` to implement pattern matching.

Implementing data types in lambda calculus is known as "Church-encoding" them (after [Alonzo Church](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alonzo_Church), who demonstrated how to do this).  Church-encoded functions are also known as "Continuation-passing style".

It's called "continuation-passing style" because instead of providing the value, you provide a function that will process the value.  So for example, instead of giving a user an `Int`, I could instead give them a value of the following type:

```
type IndirectInt = forall x . (Int -> x) -> x
```

The above type is "isomorphic" to an `Int`.  "Isomorphic" is just a fancy way of saying that we can convert any `IndirectInt` into an `Int`:

```
fw :: IndirectInt -> Int
fw indirect = indirect id
```

... and we can convert any `Int` into an `IndirectInt`:

```
bw :: Int -> IndirectInt
bw int = \f -> f int
```

... such that:

```
fw . bw = id -- Exercise: Prove this
bw . fw = id -- Exercise: Prove this
```

Using continuation-passing style, we can convert any data type into a lambda-calculus term.  Let's start with a simple type like:

```
data Either a b = Left a | Right b
```

In continuation-passing style, this would become:

```
type IndirectEither a b = forall x . (Either a b -> x) -> x
```

But Alonzo Church was smart and noticed that for any type with multiple constructors, we can just provide a separate function for each constructor.  So in the case of the above type, instead of providing a function of type `(Either a b -> x)`, we can instead provide two separate functions, one for the `a`, and one for the `b`, and that would be just as good:

```
type IndirectEither a b = forall x . (a -> x) -> (b -> x) -> x
-- Exercise: Prove that this definition is isomorphic to the previous one
```

What about a type like `Bool` where the constructors have no arguments?  Well, `Bool` is isomorphic to `Either () ()` (Exercise: Prove this), so we can just encode it as:

```
type IndirectBool = forall x . (() -> x) -> (() -> x) -> x
```

And `() -> x` is just isomorphic to `x` (Exercise: Prove this), so we can further rewrite it as:

```
type IndirectBool = forall x . x -> x -> x
```

There are only two functions that can have the above type:

```
true :: a -> a -> a
true a _ = a

false :: a -> a -> a
false _ a = a
```

Because of the isomorphism, we can guarantee that all Church encodings will have as many implementations as there were possible values of the original data type. So it's no coincidence that there are exactly two functions that inhabit `IndirectBool`, just like there are exactly two constructors for `Bool`.

But how do we pattern-match on our `IndirectBool`?  For example, with an ordinary `Bool`, we could just write:

```
expression1 :: a
expression2 :: a

case someBool of
    True  -> expression1
    False -> expression2
```

Well, with our `IndirectBool` it already comes with the tools to deconstruct itself.  We would just write:

```
myIndirectBool expression1 expression2
```

Notice that if `myIndirectBool` is `true`, it will pick the first expression, and if it is `false` it will pick the second expression, just as if we had somehow pattern-matched on its value.

Let's try to do the same thing with an `IndirectEither`.  Using an ordinary `Either`, we'd write:

```
f :: a -> c
g :: b -> c

case someEither of
    Left  a -> f a
    Right b -> g b
```

With the `IndirectEither`, we'd just write:

```
someIndirectEither f g
```

In short, when we write types in continuation-passing style, the continuations are like the case statements of a case construct, so all we are doing is passing each different case statement as arguments to the function.

This is the reason you don't need any sense of `Eq` to pattern-match on a type.  In lambda calculus, the type decides what it is "equal" to, simply by defining which argument it selects out of the ones provided to it.

So if I'm a `true`, I prove I am "equal" to `true` by always selecting my first argument.  If I'm a `false`, I prove I am "equal" to `false` by always selecting my second argument.  In short, constructor "equality" boils down to "positional equality", which is always defined in a lambda calculus, and if we can distinguish one parameter as the "first" and another as the "second", that's all we need to have the ability to "compare" constructors.

Comment: I did not expect to touch details this far when I was fancying my question, thanks for enlightenment. I had more than one "aha" when reading this. Especially the definitions of `true` and `false` until I saw the example 6 lines below made it totally clear.

Comment: While it might initially seem theoretical and farfetched, this CPS-style pattern matching actually shows up often in practice. For example, Smalltalk doesn't have if statements, but booleans have methods that receive callbacks for the true and for the false case.

Answer (score 12):

First of all, `match` and `match3` are actually exactly the same (ignoring the different strings): pattern matching in functions is desugared to a case statement.

Next, pattern matching works on *constructors* rather than arbitrary values. Pattern matching is built into the language and does not depend on boolean expressions--it just acts on the constructors directly. This is most evident with more complex matches that include some matchable terms:

```
f :: MyType -> Int
f (A a) = a + 1
f (B a b) = a + b
```

How would you rewrite these patterns into boolean expressions? You can't (without knowing anything else about `MyType`).

Instead, the pattern matching just goes by constructor. Each pattern has to be headed by a constructor--you can't write a pattern like `f (a b c)` in Haskell. Then, when the function gets a value, it can look at the value's constructor and jump to the appropriate cases immediately. This is the way it has to work for more complicated patterns (like `A a`), and is also the way it works for the simple patterns you used.

Since pattern matching just works by going to the appropriate constructor, it does not depend on `Eq` *at all*. Not only do you not have to have an `Eq` instance to pattern match, but having one also does not change how pattern matching behaves. For example, try this:

```
data MyType = TypeA | TypeB | TypeC

instance Eq MyType where 
  TypeA == TypeA = True
  TypeB == TypeC = True
  TypeC == TypeB = True
  _ == _         = False

match :: MyType → String
match TypeA = "this is type A"
match TypeB = "this is type B"
match TypeC = "this is type C"

match2 :: MyType → String
match2 a | a == TypeA = "this is type A matched by equality"
         | a == TypeC = "this is type B matched by equality"
         | a == TypeB = "this is type C matched by equality"
         | otherwise = "this is neither type A nor type B"
```

Now you've defined equality such that `TypeB` is equal to `TypeC` but not to itself. (In real life, you should ensure that equality behaves reasonably and follows the reflexive property, but this is a toy example.) Now, if you use pattern matching, `TypeB` still matches `TypeB` and `TypeC` matches `TypeC`. But if you use your guard expressions, `TypeB` actually matches `TypeC` and `TypeC` matches `TypeB`. `TypeA` is unchanged between the two.

Moreover, note how the `Eq` instance was defined *using* pattern matching. When you use a `deriving` clause, it gets defined in a similar way with code generated at compile time. So pattern matching is more fundamental than `Eq`--it is part of the language where `Eq` is just part of the standard library.

In summary: pattern matching is built into the language and works by comparing the constructor and then recursively matching on the rest of the value. Equality is usually implemented in terms of pattern matching and compares the whole value rather than just the constructor.

Answer (score 4):

The thing you are missing is that constructors in Haskell can have arguments. The type tags "themselves" are comparable by equality (at least internally, behind the scenes), but the full values are only comparable if the constituent arguments are also comparable.

So if you have a type like

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
```

then even though you can test if a type tag is  "Nothing" or "Just" (ie.; pattern match on the maybe value) in general you can't compare the full maybe unless the value of type "a" that is being held by the Just also happens to be comparable.

```
--note that your first and third examples are
--just syntactic sugar for each other...
matchMaybe mb = case mb of
    Nothing -> "Got a Nothing"
    Just _  -> "Got a Just but ignored its value"
```

It should now also be clear why its not possible to write a variation of match2 for Maybes. What would you use to test for equality in the Just case?

```
matchMaybe_2 mb | mb == Nothing = "Got a Nothing"
                | mb == Just {- ??? -} = "This case is impossible to write like this"
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I think of it, pattern matching is basically bitwise equality. It's based on types, not some abstract notion of value.

Keep in mind however, you should think of say `Int` as

```
data Int = ... | -2 :: Int | -1 :: Int | 0 :: Int | 1 :: Int | 2 :: Int | ...
```

So in a way, each integer has a different type.

That's why you can match against the `Int` say `2`.

`Eq` goes a bit further, it allows you to set things to be equal that may not be bitwise the same thing.

For example, you might have a binary tree that stores a sorted elements. Say the following:

```
  A       A
 / \     / \
B   C   B   D
     \   \
      D   C
```

May be considered equal by `Eq`, because they contain the same elements, but you wouldn't be able to check for equality here using pattern matching.

But in the case of numbers, bitwise equality is basically the same as logical equality (except perhaps positive and negative floating point `0.0`) so here `Eq` and pattern matching are pretty much equivalent.

---

For an analogy to C++, think of `Eq` as `operator==` and pattern matching as `memcmp`. You can compare a lot of types for equality simply using `memcmp`, but some you can't, if they can have different representations for "equal" values.

Comment: Thinking about numbers as constructors is totally wrong, because they actually aren't. For the reasons mentioned in the comments to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4718286/722938).

Comment: @is7s: I don't think I mentioned constructors in my answer.

Comment: `data Int = .. -1 | 0 | 1 | ..` here these numbers are called constructors as far as I know :)

Comment: No. Your edit is not different than before. For the actual implementation of `Int` it is something like `data Int = I# Int#` where `Int#` is a compiler primitive.