# How to test for a heterogeneous data constructor?

Tags: haskell

Seems like a really basic question, but if I have:

```
data LogLevel = Info | Warning | Error Int
x = Info
y = Error 13
```

I can write

```
if (x==Info)
```

but how would I write a test for type Error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Haskell do pattern matching without us defining an Eq on our data types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718084/how-does-haskell-do-pattern-matching-without-us-defining-an-eq-on-our-data-types) (not exactly of course, but hopefully reading through that thread will answer your question; but the short answer to the question you posted is "pattern matching")

Comment: Much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Error` isn't a type; it's a data constructor. You can use pattern matching to distinguish between various values of type `LogLevel`.

```
case x of
  Info -> ...
  Warning -> ...
  Error n -> ...
```

Here, not only will you take the correct "branch" depending on the value of `x`, but you also get the specific integer associated with `Error` (in `n`) when that pattern matches.